# PostgreSQL - Creating index on multiple partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-partitioning, database-deadlocks

I am trying to create indexes on multiple (1000) partitioned tables. As I'm using Postgres 10.2, I would have to do this for each of the partition separately, having to execute 1000 queries for the same.

I have figured how to do it, and it does work on environments where the table size(s) and number of transactions are very less. Below is the query to be executed for one of the table (which is to be repeated for all the tables ( user_2, user_3, etc.)

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS user_1_idx_location_id 
ON users.user_1 ( user_id, ( user_data->>'locationId') );
```

where user_data is a jsonb column

This query does not work for large tables, with high number of transactions - when I run it for all the tables at once.  Error thrown:

```
ERROR: SQL State  : 40P01
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: deadlock detected
Detail: Process 77999 waits for ShareLock on relation 1999264 of database 16311; blocked by process 77902.
Process 77902 waits for RowExclusiveLock on relation 1999077 of database 16311; blocked by process 77999
```

I am able to run it in small batches (of 25 each) - still encountering the issue at times, but running successfully when I retry it once or twice. Smaller the batch, lesser the chances of a deadlock.

I would think this happens because all the user tables ( user_1, user_2, etc) are linked to the parent table: user. I don't want to lock the entire table for the index creation (since in theory only one table is being modified at a time). Why does this happen and is there any way around this, to ensure that the index is created without the deadlocks ?

Comment: What about using CONCURRENTLY ? It takes longer, but should work on tables that are used by other processes. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html

Comment: If you want to use partitioning, I would very much recommend that you upgrade at least to v12.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Indeed, that is in the roadmap (upgrading to v12) but not possible at the moment, where we need to find a solution staying with v10.2

Comment: You are just creating needless pain for yourself. Upgrade first. This is not the only partitioning feature that was vastly improved since PostgreSQL got partitioning in v10.

Comment: @FrankHeikens It does seem like a possible solution. From the documentation, they say that it will wait for the current transactions to complete - in my case, if I then apply an index (concurrently) to one of the child table - would it wait for all transactions to this child table to complete - or would it have to wait for the parent table - as they are linked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS user_1_idx_location_id 
ON users.user_1 ( user_id, ( user_data->>'locationId') );
```